# 6 node galera cluster conflict cert failure

Tags: mysql, session, conflict, galera

We have a 6 node galera cluster and following table:

```
mysql> show create table sessions;
| Table    | Create Table
+----------+--------------
| sessions | CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`data` text,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `index_sessions_on_session_id` (`session_id`),
KEY `index_sessions_on_updated_at` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=260176483 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


mysql> desc sessions;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session_id | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| data       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We see many `wsrep_local_cert_failures` on the nodes like this:

```
SHOW status like '%wsrep%';
| wsrep_local_cert_failures | 165419
```

galera debugging displays many conflicts:

```
THD: 251130, mode: local, state: executing, conflict: cert failure, seqno: 92044718
```

Binary logging is disabled. I can identify the queries with the thread id in the general log file:

```
251130 Query SHOW FIELDS FROM sessions
251130 Query SELECT sessions.* FROM sessions WHERE sessions.session_id =   
'3d1d7f8638dbfd12ee58fa78d4f0998c' LIMIT 1
251130 Query BEGIN
251130 Query INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, data, created_at,  
updated_at) VALUES ('3d1d7f8638dbfd12ee58fa78d4f0998c',  
'BAh7BkkiDnJldHVybl90bwY6BkVGIgYv\n', '2016-01-04 10:48:52', '2016-01-04 
10:48:52')
251130 Query COMMIT
```

The Application generates the session id. Any idea?
 Whats wrong with session id's and how to resolve the conflicts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping on the hosts was the reason. We have no errors after setting the correct innodb_buffer_pool_size and restarting.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you give more details on what swapping meant? I know it has been a while...

Answer (score 0):

[A good description of "local cert failure"](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/20/understanding-multi-node-writing-conflict-metrics-in-percona-xtradb-cluster-and-galera/)

Where does the session_id come from?  It is awfully long and looks hex, so should not be utf8 and probably not varchar(255).  `UNHEX()` and put in `BINARY(16)` to get a significant shrinkage in data size.

Is the `SELECT` is attempting to see if the record already exists?  Could another node be `INSERTing` that `session_id` before you get a chance to do it?  There are multiple workarounds, each with problems.  Will that other node set the other columns to the same values?

Comment: The session_id comes from a ruby application. May be another node is inserting the same session_id, but session_id type is MUL. it souldn't cause the conflict.

Comment: `MUL` merely implies that there is an index; it is not `UNIQUE`.